# How to get JS function return from HTML button into heading?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a multiplication practice website for my science fair, and I need some help. I want the website to show whether the user input was correct or incorrect compared to the right answer. I think I coded the function right, and I know to call it with a submit button. However, I have some trouble accessing the return from the function. Where does the function return go and how do I access it?

```js
      //get random integer
      var num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (14 - 7 + 1) ) + 7;
      var num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (14 - 7 + 1) ) + 7;
      var userAnswer = 0
      document.getElementById('num1').innerHTML = num1;
      document.getElementById('num2').innerHTML = num2;
      
      
      
      function validateAnswer(num1, num2) {
       var realAnswer = num1*num2;
       var userAnswer = document.getElementById('userAnswer').value;
       if (realAnswer == userAnswer){
        return 'correct';
       }
       else {
        return 'incorrect';   
       }
    
      }
```

```html
     <h1>Multiplication Practice</h1>
     <div class="equation">
      <h2 id="num1" class="num1multiply"></h2>
      <span class="multiplicationSign">&#215;</span>
      <h2 id="num2" class="num2multiply"></h2> 
     </div class="equation">
     <br>
     <input type="integer" id="userAnswer">
     <button onclick="validateAnswer(num1, num2);" id="submit">Submit</button>
     <br>
     <h2 id="validateAnswer"></h2>
     <br>
     <br>
     <a class="back" href="main.html">back</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are calling the `validateAnswer()` function from the onclick, I would recommend *NOT* returning anything. JavaScript functions do not have to have a return value. It can just perform an action. In this case, I would recommend updating the function to have it set the result into the document.

```
function validateAnswer(num1, num2) {
    var realAnswer = num1*num2;
    var userAnswer = document.getElementById('userAnswer').value;
    var result;
    if (realAnswer == userAnswer){
        result = 'correct';
    }
    else {
        result = 'incorrect';         
    }
    document.getElementById('validateAnswer').innerHTML = result;
}
```